# Parser list well done in local but fail in heroku server

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I have an app in heroku including Order, customer, good and order function. I use mlab database. When i run i local, post order function well done but when deploy in heroku app was fail. I found out that parse list have different in local and heroku in return result. But i don't know how to fix it. Hear is my project.

**Customer class:**

```
from mongoengine import *
import mlab
from model.customer import *


class Customer(Document):
    username = StringField()
    password = StringField()
```

**Good class:**

```
from mongo
engine import *
import mlab 


class Good(Document):
    goodname = StringField()
    price = FloatField()
```

**Order class:**

```
from mongoengine import *
from model.good import Good
import mlab
from model.customer import *


class SingleOrder(EmbeddedDocument):
    good = ReferenceField("Good")
    count = IntField()

    def get_json(self):
        return {
            "good":Good.objects().with_id(self.good.id).get_json(),
            "count":self.count
        }

class Order(Document):
    items = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField("SingleOrder"))
    customer = ReferenceField("Customer")
    totalspend = FloatField()
```

**Order response:**

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from model.good import *
from model.customer import Customer
import mlab
from model.order import Order, SingleOrder


class OrderRes(Resource):
    def get(self):
        orders = Order.objects()
        return mlab.list2json(orders)
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()  
        parser.add_argument(name="items", type=list, location="json")
        parser.add_argument(name="user_id", type=str, location="json")
        parser.add_argument(name="id", type=str, location="form")
        parser.add_argument(name="count", type=int, location="form")
        body = parser.parse_args()
        items = body["items"]
        user_id = body.user_id
        total_spend = 0
        order_item = []
        for item in items:
           good_id = item["id"]
           count = item["count"]
           good = Good.objects().with_id(good_id)
           price = good.price
           print("good_id:", good_id,";count: ",count,"price: ",price)
           total_spend += price*count
           singleOrder = SingleOrder(good = good, count = count)
           order_item.append(singleOrder)
        customer = Customer.objects().with_id(user_id)
        print(mlab.item2json(order_item[0]))
        print("order_item0:",mlab.item2json(order_item[0]),"order_item1:",order_item[1])
        order = Order(items = order_item,customer = customer,
                      totalspend = total_spend)
        order.save()
        add_order = Order.objects().with_id(order.id)
        return mlab.item2json(add_order)
```

**mlab file:**

```
import mongoengine

host = "dsxxxxxx.mlab.com"
port = xxxxx
db_name = "xxxxx"
username = "xxxxx"
password = "xxxxx"
def connect():
    mongoengine.connect(db_name, host=host, port=port, username=username,password=password)
def list2json(l):
    import json
    return [json.loads(item.to_json()) for item in l]
def item2json(item):
    import json
    return json.loads(item.to_json())
```

---

After i deploy it into heroku app and post new order it was 500 Internal server Error. But in local it's OK.

I post new order:

```
{
    "items":[
        {
            "id":"593c103b4dabd9000b85b0e5",
            "count":2
        },
        {
            "id":"593c10684dabd9000b85b0e6",
            "count":3
        }
        ],
    "user_id":"593c0d5373c2132880b8a5f3"
}
```

**Heroku app log:**

```
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724170+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-11 05:16:56,722] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/order [POST]
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724203+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724204+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724205+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724206+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724206+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.finalize_request(rv)
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724207+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724208+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.make_response(rv)
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724208+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724209+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724210+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724211+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724211+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724212+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724213+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724214+00:00 app[web.1]:     app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
2017-06-11T05:16:56.724219+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: 'TypeError' object is not callable
```

I debug by return items and i see that in local items argument in parser is json type like this:

```
        {
            "id":"593c103b4dabd9000b85b0e5",
            "count":2
        },
        {
            "id":"593c10684dabd9000b85b0e6",
            "count":3
        }
```

but in server it just return list `["id","count"]`. How could i fix it?

My git repo: https://github.com/phamdinhkhanh/goodorder

Comment: When you say it works fine "local", what has changed by the deployment? Have you tried changing things in your "local' first? I would start with making your local app connect to the mlab account first if you have not already done so. This can at least pinpoint if database connection is the source of the error. Generally speaking you should have some logging available that tells you exactly what the error on the server is.

Comment: yes, at first i connect my app to mlab database and i don't change any thing before deploying in heroku. I was intact. Here is log in server:

Comment: Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44480466/edit) link on your question to post any additional information. Logs would be welcome.